# jQuery $(this).index() always showing 0

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get index of clicked class and using the following code of jQuery, but it is always showing me 0 (zero). Please help to solve this problem, thank you in advance.

```
$('.image_or_video').live('click', function(){
    var clicked_radio = $(this).index();
    alert(clicked_radio);
});
```

Comment: What does your html look like and what value do you expect to get?

Comment: Try `$('.image_or_video').index(this)`

Comment: If `.image_or_video` doesn't have siblings it's working as expected.

Comment: Post an example of the relevant html

Comment: or `$(this).index('.image_or_video')`

Comment: Did you read the docs? alot of people skip it...

Comment: @gdoron - Nope, I skipped it !

Comment: Your code will work (with lower versions of jquery), if you have more elements with same class: http://jsfiddle.net/Txghe/

Comment: @adeneo, it's o.k. until the moment you ask people why the thing you haven't learn doesn't work... :)

Comment: That's what my wife would say as well, read the manual (if I had a wife) ?

Comment: Live is deprecated.  Use .on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: So far all answers must assume something about your dom structure, perhaps you should show what your dom looks like so people can give an accurate answer?

Comment: @shubniggurath, `live` is deleted... since 1.9 (finally)

Comment: @gdoron - better still!

Comment: Most likely your element is the first child of it's parent, which would mean it's index among it's siblings will always be 0.

Comment: I guess you think $("class_selector") select all those have the same classname element, so you can use $(this) to get the current click element to get the index. $("class_selector") get all those elements have the same class name , but when you bind an event handler , it is different. jQuery will bind an event for every element, so $(this).index() will zero every time. You can use , var index = $( "div" ).index( this );

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet you want the index of the parent instead of the element you're clicking. Take a look at this code.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

The index of the `<li>` is way more useful than the `<a>`. This demo should help clear it up.

http://jsbin.com/ofapin/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

Note that `.live()` is deprecated.  You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on the parent element as follows: `$('.parent').on('click','.image_or_video',function(){...})`

To fix you problem try replacing the following line: ([Take a look on the docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/))

```
var clicked_radio = $(this).index();
```

to

```
var clicked_radio = $('.image_or_video').index(this);
```

or to

```
var clicked_radio = $(this).index('.image_or_video');
```

Comment: The last two would do the same thing in this case.

Comment: Yep @adeneo you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an event recipient object parameter to your click handler.  I couldn't get it quickly working with `live()` in the fiddle, but [here's what I did get working in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulprogrammer/HLwP3/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.image_or_video').click( function(target){
        var clicked_radio = $(target.target).index('.image_or_video');
        alert(clicked_radio);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the exact same js code, and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<p class="image_or_video">clicky</p>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('.image_or_video').live('click', function(){
    var clicked_radio = $(this).index();
    alert(clicked_radio);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What version of jquery are you using?  Live is deprecated.  Use on() instead.

Compare your code to the code above (which works with old jQuery) - what are you doing differently?

Comment: It appears you created *your own* dom to work with *his* js, but he is trying to get *his* js to work with *his* dom... which he hasn't shown us.

Comment: Good old shot in the dark.